# How can I assign dictionary values to javascript variables (jQuery / AJAX API call returned in JSON)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a well running AJAX request that queries data from a third party API that returns the data in JSON. I now want to assign the values from the returned JSON data to javascript variables to make further manipulation to the data itself in my AJAX success function before updating the frontend.

In the below example I would like to assign the value of key `name` to my Javascript `team` variable.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

**This is the returned structure:**

```
{ 
   "api":{ 
      "results":1,
      "teams":[ 
         { 
            "team_id":66,
            "name":"Barcelona",
            "code":null,
            "logo":"Not available in Demo",
            "country":"Spain",
            "founded":1899,
            "venue_name":"Camp Nou",
            "venue_surface":"grass",
            "venue_address":"Carrer d&apos;Ar\u00edstides Maillol",
            "venue_city":"Barcelona",
            "venue_capacity":99787
         }
      ],
```

**This is my AJAX request:**

```
$('ul.subbar li a').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var team_id = $(this).attr("id");
console.log(team_id);
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/teams/team/" + team_id,
  success: function(response) {
    var team_data = response
    console.log(team_data)

    team = // how to assign team name from API callback to variable

    console.log(team)

    $("#selectedClub").html(response);

    }
  });
});
```

Comment: The response is just a plain object, so just navigate it like any other object. The teams property is an array, so if the team you need is always the first or only team, index 0 would work.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But what would be the right syntax? I tried it with `team = team_data[0]` but then it says the variable team is undefined

Comment: The correct syntax would be `response.api.teams[0].name`. Writing the ajax call is way more complex than working with the response. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, one more question: What does this bracket 0 mean (maybe if there would be more teams in the object, I would pick the first one with index 0 and if there is only one team i still would need to pick it with index 0?)? You can make your comment an answer and I can approve it since it is working :)

Comment: @Phanti `[0]` is used because of the data type: an `Array` (note the square brackets: `"teams": [ ... ]`) - arrays are accessed via a numerical index. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use dot notation to navigate through objects

```
team_data.api.teams[0].name //output: "barcelona"
```

In you example there is only one item inside `teams` `array`, so the above example should works fine, but let's suppose that in your response there is more than 1 team on `teams` then you could do something like this:

```
var teamList = [];
$.each(team_data.api.teams, function(index, team){
    teamList.push(team.name);
})
```

and it will give an `array` with all team names from your `ajax response`

Answer (score 1):

put JSON in js obj variable

---

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{ <key:value>,<key:value>...}');
```

---

Make sure the text is written in JSON format, or else you will get a syntax error.

---

Use the JavaScript object in your page:
Example

---

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = obj.name + ", " + obj.country;
</script>
```